# Java Script onClick shows div: Unexpected behavior. Browser window scrolls up vertically

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have the following js which shows a div (a map) onClick. When the div shows up the browser windows scroll up vertically even if i'm at the bottom of the page. How to prevent this behavior?

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
<strong>content</strong>
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">hide</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
});
```

Comment: could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: it is because of the a tag you are using.

Comment: @Nishad Nichoos so? I don't understand... you mean a href="#"?

Comment: You don't need an account for fiddle, just click save and share the link

Comment: try removing the # from the attribute href from a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a is link element which redirects You to '#'-> it scrolls to top :). Try this one:

```
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.preventDefault()` or `return false`:

```
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(e){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});

// OR //

$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Note that if you have functions that rely on event propagation, you might want to resort the the first solution. `return false;` also stops event propagation.

Comment: Return false works, too, but you have to be aware that it stops event bubbling... so if you have any "upstream" (in terms of the DOM tree) listeners that require this bubbling event, I would say `e.preventDefault()` is a safer bet :)